# Matching Numbers that are Close in Value in Alteryx

Tags: matching, fuzzy-search, fuzzy, alteryx

I have two different datasets with different values in **Alteryx**. The one dataset serves as a lookup table for the other.

For example:

```
Name   Code Source
==================
Al      124.5    A
Bill    324.1    A
Cody    947.6    A
Dan     543.2    A
```

```
Code Description Source
=======================
121.4  qwerty       B
324.1  uiopas       B
899.7  dfghjk       B
555.6  lzxcvb       B
```

I want to perform a Fuzzy Match to join the two datasets. I'm not sure how to best merge the datasets before the Fuzzy Match since the columns are so different (like the above example). I watched some tutorials which say that I need to join the data first. How can I join the data in **Alteryx** if none of the columns truly match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shockingly not included out of the box in Alteryx. You can use an Advanced Join macro for it though... https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Engine-Works/Advanced-Join-Macro/ba-p/2355

Comment: It is a feature request since 2014... https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Ideas/Joins-on-Inequalities/idi-p/1646